# Uniform Convergence of Laurent Series using Weierstrass M-test

Tags: complex-analysis

> $G=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: 1<|z|<2\}$. Suppose $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \alpha_nz^n$ converges absolutely pointwise on some open neighborhood of $\bar{G}=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: 1 \leq |z| \leq 2\}$. We need to show that $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \alpha_nz^n$ converges unifomly on $\bar{G}=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: 1 \leq |z| \leq 2\}$.

Absolute convergence of series gave that $\sum|\alpha_n|$ converges. Now I wish to use the Weierstrass M-test. The uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha_{-n}}{z^n}$ is done. I am not able to show the uniform convergence of positive power series.

Answer (score 2):

Any open neighborhood of $\overline {G}$ contains a point with $|z| >2$ so $\sum |\alpha_n| (2+\epsilon)^{n} <\infty$ for some $\epsilon >0$. Now you can apply M-test.

Comment: It is some open neighborhood in $\bar{G}$, why does it contain a point with $|z|>2$?

Comment: Let $U$ be a neigborhood of $\overline {G}$.  $z=2$ is in $\overline {G}\subset U$ and $U$ is open. Hence there exists $r>0$ such that $|w-2|<r$ implies $w \in U$. In particular $2+\frac r 2 \in U$.

Comment: Oh, I was considering an open set inside $\bar{G}$. Thank you.